UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on two columns, but duplicates appeared: how to track down and fix?
We have table for users:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk_users_login_socnet ON public.users USING btree (login, socnet)

We had maintenance on our server, during which it was backed up and replicated to different server using pg_basebackup (comleted by our sysadmins, reportedly without errors and issues).
Since then we have errors in our logs like following:
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_users_login_socnet"
DETAIL:  Key (login, socnet)=(user@example.com, 1) already exists. (UPDATE users SET extra = COALESCE(extra, '') || hstore('udid', '') || hstore('udid_last_update', '1721646485') WHERE id = 1234567;)

In the meantime following query returns no results:
SELECT u1.login, u1.socnet
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u1.login = u2.login AND u1.socnet = u2.socnet

while it's EXPLAIN ANALYZE is:
Hash Join (cost=2817129.95..6386837.44 rows=9847200 width=18) (actual time=13654.755..31681.796 rows=15584155 loops=1)
    
Hash Cond: (((u1.login)::text = (u2.login)::text) AND (u1.socnet = u2.socnet))
    
-> Seq Scan on users u1 (cost=0.00..2490077.18 rows=15678918 width=18) (actual time=0.026..8806.271 rows=15582973 loops=1)
    
-> Hash (cost=2490077.18..2490077.18 rows=15678918 width=18) (actual time=13653.093..13653.093 rows=15582973 loops=1)
    
Buckets: 524288 Batches: 32 Memory Usage: 28510kB
    
-> Seq Scan on users u2 (cost=0.00..2490077.18 rows=15678918 width=18) (actual time=0.186..10887.626 rows=15582973 loops=1)
    
Planning time: 1.749 ms
    
Execution time: 32166.739 ms

But this query:
SELECT t1.login, t1.socnet, t2.login, t2.socnet
FROM users AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, login, socnet FROM users) AS t2
ON t2.login = t1.login AND t1.socnet = t2.socnet
WHERE t1.id != t2.id

shows a list of duplicated rows with same login and socnet, which to me makes no sense. Here's respective EXPLAIN ANALYZE:
Hash Join (cost=2817129.95..6411455.44 rows=9847199 width=36) (actual time=17015.349..33466.957 rows=1182 loops=1)
    
Hash Cond: (((t1.login)::text = (users.login)::text) AND (t1.socnet = users.socnet))
    
Join Filter: (t1.id <> users.id)
    
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 15583110
    
-> Seq Scan on users t1 (cost=0.00..2490077.18 rows=15678918 width=22) (actual time=0.034..9902.685 rows=15583110 loops=1)
    
-> Hash (cost=2490077.18..2490077.18 rows=15678918 width=22) (actual time=14344.722..14344.722 rows=15583110 loops=1)
    
Buckets: 524288 Batches: 32 Memory Usage: 30951kB
    
-> Seq Scan on users (cost=0.00..2490077.18 rows=15678918 width=22) (actual time=0.024..11382.363 rows=15583110 loops=1)
    
Planning time: 1.764 ms
    
Execution time: 33467.260 ms

The PostgreSQL server version is 9.6
My questions are:

What is happening? Why do I have duplicate data within UNIQUE CONSTRAINT?
Why I have different results for INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN?
What might have happened to DB structure and how to debug it? Where to look for hints on what's broken?
How to fix this to consistent state?


When you say "backed up and replicated to a different server", do you mean that you promoted the replica, and the problem happens on the promoted replica?

Yes, a pg_basebackup replicated data to a set of different servers (i believe it's a cluster), which then was brought in behind a HAproxy and then new master was re-elected. That is, if I understood sysadmin's description correctly.

You got data corruption, because the standby server that got promoted was running on a machine with a different setup. In particular, the C library must have had a different version (probably one of them glibc < 2.28, the other glibc >= 2.28). The definition of the collations on these two versions was different, so an index on a string expression was corrupted on the standby.
See this and this article for a more detailed explanation.
To fix the corruption, you have to rebuild all indexes on strings. If rebuilding the indexes leads to an error, because you already got duplicate values in a table, you have to delete data until the inconsistency is fixed.
Always make sure that you replicate between machines with the same version of the C library.

Regarding the final sentence: If after offline (i.e. no traffic) replication to new servers I rebuild indexes there and then set new servers as masters, will it still cause issues for old servers (then be regarded as slaves)?

Could you try that question again, in better English?

if I replicate current master A with pg_basebackup onto a system B with newer glibc version, then rebuild indexes on B, then promote B to be new master, then is it ok to still have A as a replica of B (even though their C library differ)?
Should A be ruled out of the system as soon as possible or can it still be around for a while?

No, that won't work. You cannot rebuild an index on a standby server (it is read-only). You have to rebuild the indexes after you promote the standby. If you then want to make A a standby, you have to rebuild A, and it will now have the same problem. Do not replicate between machines with a different C library, unless you are ready to rebuild indexes after promotion.
